# Android studio firebase submission form

Tags: android, firebase

I'm new to Android studio. I was able to create login and auth for my app using firebase.

I'm now trying to create a submission form for the user to create and log all the fields in firebase. I would also need the ability as admin to approve the submission request and notify user by push notification or email. The email is one of the fields in  the submission form.

Looking for some guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebase Realtime Database + Firebase Functions.
[You can see examples here.](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use FirebaseDatabase for that, go through this to set things up-

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

So first of all, add a EditText fields (simplest way) for each entry you want in your xml such as emails, password, etc.

```
<EditText
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="Enter Email"/>
</EditText>
```

Next, in your java file, convert these entries to strings.

Create a DatabaseReference (Make sure you have included firebase database library in you app level build.gradle file) and point to the location where you want to store the form entries.

Create a HashMap in which you store id and entry of each field. Directly upload this map instead of uploading each and every field separately.

Don't forget to check that the entries aren't empty.
Somewhat like this-

```
//global variables in class
private EditText email;
private DatabaseReference mdatabase;
//inside onCreate() method
mdatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Wherever you want to store this data");
email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailf);
String mymail = email.getText().toString();
  if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(myname)&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(mymail)&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(mypass))
{
//create a map
HashMap< String,String> hm =  
   new HashMap< String,String>(); 
   hm.put("email", mymail); 
   hm.put("password", mypass); 
   hm.put("name", myname); 
mdatabase.setValue(hm).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
if(task.isSuccessful())
{
//do whatever you want, your details have been uploaded to your database- mdatabase
}
}
});
}
```

Push Notifications can be implemented using Firebase Cloud Messaging service and node.js

You'll also need to learn about Firebase Functions, very necessary.

Begin here-
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

and here-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsCBCudx58g

and then here-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MYgZQjX7N0&list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hjxP_CHAhjXQN3zrcEhluF_

I hope this answered your question!